# Controlling foundation 4 accordion speed

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've come across Foundation4 3 days ago. My knowledge about javascript and  Jquery are so-so. That's why I'm having a hard time figuring out how to solve my problem.

```
<div class="large-3 columns right">
     <div class="section-container accordion" data-section="accordion">
          <section>
              <p class="title" data-section-title><a href="#">Staff Favourites</a></p>
              <div class="content" data-section-content>
                <ul class="side-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Morbi vitae eleifend </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Praesent suscipit    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cras et justo non    </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Fusce vel leo        </a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Vestibulum ante      </a></li>
                </ul>
              </div>
          </section>
     </div>
</div>
```

It work's fine but I want the dropdown animation to look smoother, the thing is I tried looking for solutions on the internet but couldn't find anything related to foundation 4. 
can anyone please help me?

Comment: While looking for answers I found this, (http://jsfiddle.net/76MbN/4/) I tried using it but the entire content does not show anymore.